# Can Snowflake stage Standalone without the help of any cloud or lock machine?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema, snowflake-pipe

For staging in Snowflake, we need S3 AWS layer or Azure or Local machine. Instead of this, can we FTP a file from a source team directly to Snowflake internal storage, so that, from there the Snowpipe can the file and load to our Snowflake table.

If yes, please tell how. If no, please confirm that as well. If no, won't that is a big drawback of Snowflake to depend on other platforms every time.

Comment: what do you mean by a "lock machine"? also "from a source team"?

Comment: also, no - you cannot FTP a file directly to a Snowflake internal stage. It needs to exist somewhere that can be configured as an external stage (e.g. AWS S3) or on a local machine that can use the PUT command (https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-local-file-system-stage.html) to send it to an internal stage.

Comment: Also note that if you're not using an integration with an external service like AWS then you will need to call the Snowpipe REST endpoint to trigger the load from the internal stage into Snowflake.

Answer (score 0):

You can use just about any driver from Snowflake to move files to Internal stage on Snowflake. ODBC, JDBC, Python, SnowSQL, etc. FTP isn't a very common protocol in the cloud, though. Snowflake has a lot of customers without any presence on AWS, Azure,  or GCP that are using Snowflake without issues in this manner.